# Show banner asking for nominations only when user has enough reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, election, notification-bar

When visiting [Tor Stack Exchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/), I'm seeing the following banner:

> Want to help moderate this community? [**We need more candidates in the ongoing election!**](https://tor.stackexchange.com/election)

[image: Tor homepage with banner]

It's a decent idea for getting more candidates, but I have only 155 reputation, not enough for nominating (300) by a wide margin. So the banner isn't useful for me, and I'd rather not see it. I don't get the inbox notification when the nomination phase starts either.

Comment: Good one! Better to split the banner in two versions. This one, and one for those that don't qualify making them aware that there is an election ongoing and that you need X reputation to candidate yourself.

Comment: It also appear to anonymous visitors, i.e. people who are not even logged in. :/

Comment: The community bulletin (the sidebar widget on the top right) already shows there's an ongoing election; that's enough for me (and for anonymous visitors).

Comment: I half-disagree with this. For example, if I see this banner on Physics, where I have about 250 rep, the banner would encourage me to participate more, get to 300 rep, and nominate myself. This banner does not look pointless.

Comment: If it's by a wide margin, however, it is sensible to only show the banner once the user gets to 250 or something like that.

Comment: The problem with that is to define "wide margin". With a small community you might not get that many upvotes (or downvotes, but they don't contribute to increasing your rep, so let's forget that possibility) to your questions/answers (there might not even be that many (new) questions to answer. I think my reputation grew much faster on mathematics.SE than on bricks.SE.

Answer (score 5):

That banner doesn't actually have anything to do with elections. It's actually a system message that can contain any text relevant to the site - it just so happens to have been used this time to draw extra attention to the ongoing election. You don't get the inbox notification because that *is* tied into the election system.

We're not interested in modifying the system message behavior to be able to limit its visibility to only certain users under rare circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

No, that banner is fine to show to everyone, even to users that can't nominate yet or anonymous users for that matter.

Here is my reasoning.

There was already a plea on Meta from a CM for candidates to nominate: [2019 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/355/7029). The banner is the ultimate attempt to reach anyone that might be able or knows someone to run for moderator on that site. Its goal is to reach as many users as possible to make that election happen. It has already been proven that normal measures didn't work. The banner is the last resort.

So instead of posting on Meta you should have stalked Tor.se users to nominate themselves ;)

*we can debate better wording so it doesn't simply copy the community bulletin*

Comment: Sorry, even as last resort it doesn't justify the noise. It's useless for users with less than 300 rep. And if a site doesn't have enough active users who are willing to moderate it, it should be closed. Sad, but keeping it alive by force is even worse. SE shouldn't plead for people to do those things. It should be the reverse, if anything.