# Let users close/hide system messages, such as the "Please nominate yourself" bar at the top

Tags: feature-request, system-message

For the past hour, whenever I went to Music Stack Exchange, I saw the "Please nominate yourself" bar at the top, and there was no way to disable it. I think that adding a feature to close system messages at the top would be useful. Many users (like me) don't even meet the requirements. This would improve the site experience for those users and the users who don't want to become a moderator, and in other cases where a system message is not applicable to the user viewing it.

Even if one does meet the requirements but doesn't wish to volunteer, this message is currently at the top of *every single page* on the site - on both [MusicSE](https://music.stackexchange.com/) & [Hardware Recs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) as of now.

Other messages of this type in the past have had a simple 'don't ask again' in the form of an X, top right.
This would be such a simple fix, as presumably the code to do that already exists.
[image]

A [related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332658/show-banner-asking-for-nominations-only-when-user-has-enough-reputation) was previously declined, with the reason that:

> We're not interested in modifying the system message behavior to be able to limit its visibility to only certain users under rare circumstances.

This request asks for *all* types of system messages to be able to be closed or hidden, so that reason doesn't apply to this question.

Comment: There are probably lots of high-rep users who are too young to be a moderator. These users should be able to disable the bar.

Comment: Related: [Show banner asking for nominations only when user has enough reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332658/show-banner-asking-for-nominations-only-when-user-has-enough-reputation), ["Please consider nominating in the current election" banner is shown to anonymous and low-rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377251/please-consider-nominating-in-the-current-election-banner-is-shown-to-anonymou)

Comment: Was previously requested and declined: [Show banner asking for nominations only when user has enough reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332658/show-banner-asking-for-nominations-only-when-user-has-enough-reputation)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog In my interpretation, that question was asking to not show the banner, whereas this question is asking to provide a way to close the banner.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace The answer there still applies - it's a system message that's free-form and in that particular case used to promote the election, and the team is not interested in changing its behavior in specific cases. If this were edited to more generally ask for all types of system messages to be closeable, I'd remove my duplicate vote.

Comment: I'm above 300 rep, but I'm still ineligible, so this doesn't apply.

Comment: @mathlander As I said before, even though the exact request there is different, the answer there also applies to this request - it's a freeform system message and the team is not interested in changing its behavior to make it show for only a subset of users. Per [policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635/377214), *[on] meta sites, however, it's not unusual for a question to be closed as a duplicate of another question that may not be asking the* exact *same question, if the answers to that post address the question being asked*.

Comment: Vote to reopen. The dupe is 'Why do I see the banner?', this is 'How do I get rid of it?' which is a question I am currently fully invested in. Usually you can dismiss these once you've seen them, but this one is a perma-nag. I have no intention of volunteering to become a mod, though I'm quite happy to be involved in the rest of the process. This is all it needs - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvRjj.jpg

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog *"...the team is not interested in changing its behavior to make it show for only a subset of users."*  Why not? Is this because of a specific policy?

Comment: @Theodore that banner in particular is effectively being used as a stop-gap solution due to no better solution for this particular message existing, apparently. Though i don't see why they can't use any of the other banners for this. This banner in particular (system message banner) doesn't make sense to be limited by election eligibility.

Comment: I also see no reason for this to be closed... The two questions are asking for two different features. Just because they weren't interested in doing anything about it 4 years ago doesn't mean this question shouldn't exist anyway, as yet another feature that would be useful for a possible different banner used for this purpose.

Comment: One downside of this being implemented: the tag wiki of [system-message] would have to be changed.

Comment: @mathlander - that's not a downside, it's just a need for a new tag. Doesn't even enter the equation. You keep dragging this back to your initial 'Why do I see it?' followed by, 'how much trouble will it cause?' Neither of these are relevant to the plot. Stick with the simple 'Why can I not dismiss this, once I've read it?'